# Tab completion for unicode (Python 3/Julia) using emacs?

Tags: python, unicode, emacs, julia, tab-completion

Is there a way to configure emacs so that we could use tab completion to type Unicode variables, used for Python 3 and Julia? For example

```
\gamma -> tab -> γ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative is to call `set-input-method` with `C-x RET C-\`, choose `TeX`, and type `\gamma`, which will be automatically replaced with `γ`. You should then be able to toggle input methods with `C-\`. Alternatively, if you wish, you can add `(setq default-input-method "TeX")` to your init file and use `C-\` to go into `TeX` input more quickly and do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a completion-at-point for julia latexsubs a while back.  Its just the following (`julia-latexsubs` is the hash of latex symbols defined in `julia-mode`)

```
(defun julia-completion-at-point ()
  (let ((bnds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (when bnds
      (cond
       ;; complete latex symbol when current symbol is prefixed
       ;; by '\'
       ((eq (char-before (car bnds)) ?\\)
        (list (1- (car bnds)) (cdr bnds) julia-latexsubs
              :annotation-function
              #'(lambda (arg)
                  (gethash arg julia-latexsubs ""))))))))
```

Then in your julia-mode hook, or `ess-julia-mode-hook`

```
  (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'julia-completion-at-point nil t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [company-math](https://github.com/vspinu/company-math). My config is [here](https://github.com/malb/emacs.d/blob/master/malb.org#latex)